# Accessing Google home for usage statistics

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I hope you can help me with a problem:

I want to create a web application that requests user data from a Google Home device. I then want to create an interface that summarizes all this data and shows convenient data analytics to the user. For example: How many times I switched a light on during a week, or what music I'm listening to, or which light are on or off at a certain moment.

The problem is that I have no idea where to begin, I've been searching through Google and stackoverflow without avail. I came across a site called home-assistant.io, but that seems to be a program that consists of different modules and has the Google assistant "on the side" instead of using the Google assistant to gather the data.

So I guess it boils down to is it possible to use the Google Home to gather usage statistics, or isn't that possible (yet)?

Answer (score 2):

In short - it isn't.

**Users** can see what they've done using their Google account, including through the Assistant, using https://myactivity.google.com.

However, **third-party developers** have no access to on-device activity, no access to the content at myactivity.google.com, and no way to intercept or view what a user is doing using the Assistant. In short - no way to gather statistics outside of their own, specific, Action.

There are lots of reasons this isn't allowed, but probably the biggest is security and privacy. Google gets a lot of criticism for collecting this information, and would probably get even more if it was possible for those outside Google to get it as well. (Google also has a business reason for limiting outside access to this information, admittedly.)